# Is there a simple method to split a String variable in two?

Tags: python, variables, format

Still very new to python, and am wondering if it is possible to split a string variable for formatting purposes into two sections, and if so what is the simplest and most common method?

This is what I have tried, but this method does not work for more than one {}.

```
Subject= 'A is {}, and B is {}'
Subject_matter= 'A' and 'B'
Subject.format(Subject_matter)
```

I would ideally like to end up with

```
A is A, and B is B
```

Comment: it's possible to format multiple placeholders with `format` method. Just pass multiple values like:
`Subject.format('a', 'b')`

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am aware of this method, but was wondering if there was some way to use another variable to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argument expansion (note the *):

```
Subject= 'A is {}, and B is {}'
Subject_matter= 'A','B'
print(Subject.format(*Subject_matter))
```

This treats the iterable as separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want to do, you can do the following:

```py
subject = 'A is {}, and B is {}'
formatted_subject = subject.format('A', 'B')
```

There is many other ways and options to format your strings which you may learn about [here](https://pyformat.info).